# Cordova Android WebRTC Won't Capture Video - AUDO ONLY. Permissions issue?

Tags: cordova, webrtc, android-permissions

I have cordova app that uses WebRTC and RTCPeerConnection to connect two clients to allow them to chat. It's working successfully in the browser and on iOS (with a webRTC shim). However, only audio is being captured and sent on Android, no video! Here's the code. The video isn't even being attached to the #localVideo elem ([which might be a whole other problem in and of itself](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253465))!

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia
navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function (stream) {
  var video = document.getElementById('localVideo')
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
  video.play()
  window.myRTC.pc1.addStream(stream)
  console.log(stream)
  console.log('adding stream to pc1')
  window.myRTC.setupDC1()
  window.myRTC.pc1.createOffer(function (desc) {
    window.myRTC.pc1.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {}, function () {})
    console.log('created local offer', desc)
  },
  function () { console.warn("Couldn't create offer") },
  window.myRTC.sdpConstraints)
}, function (error) {
  console.log('Error adding stream to pc1: ' + error)
})
```

I'm fairly convinced this is a permissions issue. Here is a screenshot of the app's permissions on my phone:
[image: my app's permissions]

You can see that "record audio" is present, but not camera, or capture video.

Here's my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="org.unicomm" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
     ....
     <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/manifest" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
            <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Strangely, not all of those permissions get written to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="org.unicomm" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
</manifest>
```

As a last ditch effort, I tried using a [permissions plugin](https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permission):

```
var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
permissions.requestPermissions(
    [permissions.CAMERA,permissions.RECORD_AUDIO,permissions.RECORD_VIDEO],
    function(status) {console.log(status)
        if(!status.hasPermission) {
            errorCallback();
        } else {
            run();
        }
     },
     function() {
         alert("We need those permissions!")
     }
);
```

But it simply returns `{hasPermission: true}`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know who the clown is that downvoted... Especially without giving a comment or reason. If My question was bad, or wrong in some way, I would've really loved to understand why.

It ended up being a permissions problem. I don't know what I was doing wrong with my config.xml, thought I was following the cordova docs. Ended up installing [this plugin](https://github.com/mircoc/cordova-plugin-settings-hook). It finally made the changes to AndroidManifest.xml that I was requesting be made from my config.xml.

Here is the config.xml I used:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="org.unicomm" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    ...
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-settings-hook" spec="~0.2.3" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="stun:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
            <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       </config-file>
    </platform>
    ...
</widget>
```

WebRTC now working! Woot!

Comment: could you please share complete code for webrtc to work with android + ios?, struggling from days to work this thing :/ .. thanks

Comment: @user969068 [https://github.com/adam-hanna/serverless-webrtc](https://github.com/adam-hanna/serverless-webrtc)

Comment: Thank you @Adam , I checked the repo, is it possible to have app.814711a87cebfef47649.js unminified version instead the minified one from here? tree/master/cordova/www/static/js..

Comment: @user969068, the unminified stuff is everything in the vue directory :)

Comment: `"android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"` doesn't exist I'm afraid

Comment: Did not get permissions till i modified the config file as follows:

<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest"  mode="merge"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

I think xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" is mandatory now?

Comment: Your plugin doesn't work for me. I modify AndroidManifest.xml file directly, and my cordova build apk could use webrtc correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I got something working:

As of Android Marshmallow, you have to ask for permission at runtime.  This is what the "[cordova-plugin-android-permission](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions)" plugin you tried is supposed to do; however as you mentioned, the requestPermissions() function doesn't seem to do anything (other than return the current permission).

I got the requestPermissions() call (from the [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions)) working with these steps:

1. Indicate you're targeting Android Marshmallow, by adding this to your config.xml. (Per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41595068/7470370 )

   `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />`
2. The `<uses-permissions>` lines also seem to be required, and for sure to support older versions.  I used this (as my case does not need audio).

   `<config-file platform="android" target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest" mode="add">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   </config-file>`
3. As an aside, the WebView in KitKat does not support webrtc well, so I also add this to exclude unsupported versions:

   `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" /> <!-- 21=lollipop -->`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! This thread pointed me in the right direction. I had an issue with the final version of the config.xml being built by ionic-cordova, getting this error:

> .../platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml:51: AAPT:
>   error: unbound prefix.

I had to switch over the xml tag format to have `name="android.permission.CAMERA" platform="android"` broken out instead of `android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"` for it to work. Now it works great.

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.CAMERA" platform="android" />
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" platform="android" />
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" platform="android" />
    </config-file>
</platform>
```